# Is this set bounded?

Tags: general-topology, upper-lower-bounds

Is the set $A = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x+z = 0\}$ bounded? According to my source it should be, but can't $x$ and $z$ take on every value therefore the set is not bounded?

---

Edit: For the solution of the source I was looking at to work out, only the intersection of $A$ and $B = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ had to be bounded, which is the case, since the intersection must satisfy both equations and therefore all $|x|,|y|,|z|$ are smaller or equal to 1.

Comment: It is not bounded. $y$ can be anything.

Comment: And furthermore, $x$ and $z$ can have arbitrarily large magnitudes. What is your source on this?

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks. And if I intersect this set with a bounded set in the form $B  = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2 = 1\}$ will the intersection be bounded? Because then my solution would still make sense.

Comment: @DonThousand However the set $B$ in the above comment is again not bounded.

Comment: @WhatsUp Because of $z$ being without a bound?

Comment: Yes. The intersection of $A$ and $B$ is finally bounded, but you should prove it...

Comment: @WhatsUp The intersection would be a set that satisfies both equations $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and $x+z =0$. From the first equation it follows that $|x| \leq 1$ and therefore $|z| \leq 1$. Now all variables have a bound. Would that be enough?

Comment: That's now a perfect argument.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $S=\{(0,n,0): n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is subset of $A$ and $S$ is not bounded. Hence given set $A$ is Not bounded.